# Internet Explorer not rendering svg text correctly when using text-anchor and textLength attributes

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, svg

I have noticed that the below web page does not render correctly in IE 11.  It does work perfectly in Google Chrome.

The text elements in the example below that are marked with "text-anchor:end" are not anchored properly with the end of the text in IE.

It looks like combing the "text-anchor: end" attribute with the textLength attribute is causing the problem.  When the textLength attribute is removed, it behaves as expected.

I have not been able to find any information about this issue online.   Is this a known bug?  Is there a work around?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<svg height="1000" width="1150">

    <text text-anchor="start" textLength="200px" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" font-family="Lucida Console" font-size="15" x="600" y="80">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</text>
    <text text-anchor="end" textLength="200px" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" font-family="Lucida Console" font-size="15" x="600" y="100">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</text>

    <text text-anchor="start" textLength="300px" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" font-family="Lucida Console" font-size="15" x="600" y="150">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</text>
    <text text-anchor="end" textLength="300px" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" font-family="Lucida Console" font-size="15" x="600" y="170">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</text>

    <text text-anchor="start" textLength="500px" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" font-family="Lucida Console" font-size="15" x="600" y="220">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</text>
    <text text-anchor="end" textLength="500px" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" font-family="Lucida Console" font-size="15" x="600" y="240">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</text>

</svg>
```

Comment: It looks like they are adjusting the start position of the text based on the unadjusted text length, and then are stretching the text afterwards.  If you include a version of your elements without a `textLength` attribute, you'll see that all the other versions align with it on the start point.  Definitely a bug.  Report it at https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is not to use text-anchor: end (or middle), just text-anchor: start.
Only you have to calculate the start position, which is quite easy, since you know the exact length of the rendered text (you have just set it with the textLength property), so the new x value will be (old x - textLength) if you planned to use text-anchor: end, or (old x - textLength / 2) in case of text-anchor: middle.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, rather than depending on the textLength and the lengthAdjust attributes to set the font spacing and glyph size, I sized the font based on the actual string length (in pixels) and the size of the available space (in pixels).  Below is the code I used.  Note, I am using d3.js.

```
 var lTitleWidth = title[0][0].getBBox().width;
    if (lTitleWidth > lMaxTitleWidth) {
        var lFactor = lMaxTitleWidth / lTitleWidth;
        title.attr({ "font-size": parseInt(title.attr("font-size")) * lFactor });
    }
```

This workaround does not give the exact same behavior.  Since the font size is now smaller, the font height is reduced as well, which it would not have been had IE worked as it should.